# System.Web.Optimization - Make Minified JS and CSS Cache Forever

Tags: iis, cache-control, asp.net-optimization

I would like the output of bundles minified with the built-in JsMinify and CssMinify to have "cache forever" semantics so that browsers don't keep requesting them over and over.  The resultant URLs are hashed based on the content so there's no sense in not using "cache forever" semantics on URLs like this.

Preferably, I would like to do this without having to write my own custom bundle transform.  Can this be done?  Either by manipulating settings on the Bundle, or by putting the right things in the web.config file?